# ASP.NET Adding Multiple footers rows to Gridview

Tags: asp.net

i.e at the moment I am adding a footer row to my gridview as follows

```
    Protected Sub gvShoppingCart_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvShoppingCart.RowDataBound
    ' If we are binding the footer row, let's add in our total
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
        e.Row.Cells(5).Text = "<strong>Total Cost:</strong>"
        e.Row.Cells(6).Text = ShoppingCart.Instance.GetSubTotal().ToString("C")
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I add more footer rows i.e. Total Discount, Total Saved etc likewise as above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code for inserting a new row, based on the footer row. You could modify it to insert multiple rows.

```
    Protected Sub gvShoppingCart_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvShoppingCart.DataBound
        Dim grid as GridView = CType(sender, GridView)

        ''gets the current footer row to clone
        Dim footer As GridViewRow = grid.FooterRow
        Dim numCells = footer.Cells.Count

        Dim newRow As New GridViewRow(footer.RowIndex + 1, -1, footer.RowType, footer.RowState)

        ''have to add in the right number of cells
        ''this also copies any styles over from the original footer
        For i As Integer = 0 To numCells - 1
            Dim emptyCell As New TableCell
            emptyCell.ApplyStyle(grid.Columns(i).ItemStyle)

            newRow.Cells.Add(emptyCell)
        Next

        newRow.Cells(5).Text = "Total Discount:"
        newRow.Cells(6).Text = "55.00"

        ''add new row to the gridview table, at the very bottom
        CType(grid.Controls(0), Table).Rows.Add(newRow)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Only the solution with creating a new `GridViewRow` worked for me now in 2022, for a WebForms web app. Not those using the creation of new `TableRow` that I've tried from other answers on the same subject (multiple GridView footers rows).

Answer (score 1):

Using the default control there is only one footer row, therefore, you would have to manage the display of any additional items manually, most likely by inserting 
 or similar tags to create additional lines.

You could do a custom template for the fields in the footer to help control the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `<FooterTemplate>` in `<asp:TemplateField>` of the `GridView`

Here is an example: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/07/display-total-in-gridview-footer.html

A better option would be to use the `ListView` control. It offers a lot more flexibility for layout.